# Using RInside destructor

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

A simple experiment shows that only one RInside instance is allowed per thread at a time.

```
#include <RInside.h>

int main() {
  RInside R1;
  R1.parseEval("cat('Hello, R1\n')");
  RInside R2;
  R2.parseEval("cat('Hello, R2\n')");
  return 0;
}
```

The program crashes with the following output:

```
Hello, R1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  can only have one RInside instance

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

However the result of another experiment with succesive RInside instances creation is not quite clear.

```
#include <RInside.h>

int main() {
  RInside *R1 = new RInside();
  R1->parseEval("cat('Hello, R1\n')");
  delete R1;
  RInside *R2 = new RInside();
  R2->parseEval("cat('Hello, R2\n')");
  delete R2;
  return 0;
}
```

This program buzzes at the moment of R2 creation. The previous output looks like this:

```
Hello, R1
Lost warning messages
```

**Isn't R1 destructor call sufficient for the proper RInside cleanup?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please** -- that was all just discussed on the rcpp-devel mailing list [and here is a link to the entire (short) thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/3812).  In a nutshell it is *not* the RInside destructor but *rather the R API itself* which RInside merely provides via an easier-to-use C++ wrapping.

[A follow-up post has been sent to r-devel as well](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/31663) and in that thread Simon clearly states that because of a number of static globals in R itself, a fix is unlikely.